# check if item exists in core data EFFICIENTLY

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data

So I browsed stack for the answer to my question, and everyone is saying that count requests are the way to go. I found that to be false when I ran unit tests on my app.

```
for number in largeNumber {  //large number is 1000

  let count = try self.context.count(for: countRequest)

   }
```

operation took 0.2 seconds!!

whereas

```
  for number in largeNumber {  //large number is 1000

let fetch = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest)

 }
```

//operation took 0.158 seconds!

so whats everyone blabbering about count requests being more efficient. It makes it worse if anything. That said, is there a more efficient way of checking if a value exists in core data

Answer (score 0):

The results of your tests may be due to a difference in what's being done in the two versions. **Count** returns the number of found managed objects.  **Fetch** is likely to be populating the attributes, relationships etc.

Core Data likely caches this information so that an identical fetch request doesn't have to repeat.  The result (in your example) could be equivalent of 1 fetch request and 999 no-operations.

Count should be the most efficient as it's not populating the managed objects.  What happens if you loop 1000 times but have a different predicate each pass?